# How I can detect the first access of user in my website using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a React application with a tour guide on the page, but I using localStorage to set the firstAccess key to true when the user visit the functionality after register, but I think that can have more efficient ways to get the information about the first access of user, using something with User Agent maybe? The question is, what's the common used way to know if the user is the first access? I can get this with a simple Javascript code?

The tour is starting when the key firstAccess on localStorare is equal to "true", but the problem is that I setting this key to false when he finish the tour, but others page needs shows their own tour, but the key is seted false in this time.

I'm using this to start tour:

```
 localStorage.setItem("newUser", true);
```

But this key is seted after the user register, and used on other pages:

```
  function userRegistered() {
    const auxStorage = localStorage.getItem("newUser");

    if (auxStorage === "true") {
      setTourRun(true);
    }
  }
```

And when the tour is done I set key to false:

```
  function cancelTour() {
    setTourRun(false);
    localStorage.removeItem("newUser");
  }
```

Because this I can't use this same key in other tour pages.

The expect result is that I can identify first use in each page and starts the individual tour of each page.

Comment: Do it in reverse, if "hasDoneTour != true" then do the tour and set it to true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by efficiency... Local Storage is plenty efficient.  But, I think you should think about this problem the other way around.

Local Storage is going to be *empty* when you first visit, so set your Local Storage item after you've done your check.

```
if (!localStorage.getItem('previouslyVisited')) {
  runTour();
  localStorage.setItem('previouslyVisited', 'true');
}
```

Comment: It's a good way to do this, you give me some idea, use the value of the key to set the page of last access, like if I visited dashboard set the value "fromDash" and this is confirming that only dash is visited, and others with the same logic, and a conditional to know if that page was visited. Or using this way in each page with differents keys also works, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Json Object for checking progress for a tours.

For example:

```
var progress = {
    tour1: true,
    tour2: false,
    tour3: false
};


changeProgress("tour2");

function changeProgress(tourNumber) {
    var p = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("progress"));
    if (tourNumber === "tour1") {
        p.tour1 = true;
    } else if (tourNumber === "tour2") {
        p.tour2 = true;
    } else if (tourNumber === "tour3") {
        p.tour3 = true;
    }

    localStorage.setItem("progress", JSON.stringify(p));
}
```

Comment: The tour is not sequential, I think that's work well, but sequentialy I can do this passing previous step with props, but I can't know if is the first access on certain page.